# Is it possible to make an @property private?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Someone said that I could add an `private` keyword to @property(...) ... really?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objective-C only allows private, protected, and public modifiers on instance variables, although you can essentially make a property (or method) private by declaring it in the implementation (`.m`) file rather than the header (`.h` file).